# Linking a user's browser session with a message received via Twilio webhook

Tags: javascript, twilio

We're creating an experience where we'd like the user to send an SMS to a number displayed in the browser. When the message is received by our Twilio webhook, we'd like to trigger an event in that user's browser.

The only way we've found to do this so far is by generating a random hash for the browser session, and getting the user to include this hash in the body of the SMS. When the webhook receives an SMS, it checks the message body for a hash and sends an event via WebSockets to the browser session associated with that hash.

It works, but it's not the most seamless experience. There was a [Grolsch campaign](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwTVl4iaXoU) a couple of years ago that did a similar thing (no longer live) but from the looks of the video they didn't seem to have this authentication step and still managed to show the user's response on screen.

Unless they had individual Twilio numbers for each session, I'm not sure how else it could be achieved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Twilio developer evangelist here.

My guess is that you're final idea was correct and they had multiple Twilio numbers in a pool that they could grab from for each viewer. Then, once the interaction takes place the number can be returned to the pool and used for another viewer. You could also dynamically grow and shrink the number of numbers in the pool based on demand. This tutorial shows how you can [buy numbers on the fly in order to mask user's numbers from each other](https://www.twilio.com/docs/tutorials/walkthrough/masked-numbers/node/express) and this technique could be used here.

You could also do this with one Twilio number if you knew the viewer's phone number up front. Then you could just lookup the user from the number that sent the message.

Comment: Thanks Phil (saw you talk at Front-end London a while back!). I thought this might be the case, thanks for confirming. Getting the user to enter their number in the browser first might prove to be a better experience actually – we can send them a text first to initiate the conversation, to which they can just reply to – saving them having to type in the number at all. I'll check out the tutorial too. Keen to keep costs down by minimising the amount of numbers we need though. It's for a small creative campaign so hopefully it'll be fun anyway! :-)

Comment: Cheers Peter, glad this has given you some ideas. Drop me an email (philnash@twilio.com) if you need any more help or want to share the campaign when it's live (I'd love to see it!).